# How to use the scrollTo function?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am looking for a way to scroll from `<div id="myButton">Home</div>` to the centre of another div point . The aim of this is because I have 4 pages and I want them to be horizontally next to each other with a navigation bar (which stays perfectly in the centre) that follows the pages. 
Why is this not working?

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzXub/763/)

```
$('div#myButton').click(function () {
    $.scrollTo($('div#myDiv'), 500);
});
```

I have:

```
<body>

<div id="myButton">yo</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
.....
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="myDiv">hello</div>

<script>

$("div#myButton").click(function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("div#myDiv").offset().top   }, 2000);
 });

</script>


</body>
```

But it is still not working?!!

Comment: [There is no `scrollTo` function in jQuery](http://jquery.com/?s=scrollto). Are you referring to the [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it *without* plugin.

Just a small change in plan .

```
$("div#myButton").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("div#myDiv").offset().top   }, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: this only does y direction not x?

Comment: I am sorry but I have totally forgotten you dont just put your code in script tags do you? you have to put something else before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollTop` to scroll. `otherDiv.offset().top` will place you at the top of the div and adding `otherDiv.height() / 2` will scroll down to the center of the div

```
$('div#myButton').click(function () {
    var otherDiv = $('div#myDiv');
    $("html, body").scrollTop(otherDiv.offset().top + otherDiv.height() / 2);
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHvcU/), the top of your page will be exactly on the center of the div

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript function, not a jquery function, and is the same as window.scroll.

```
window.scrollTo( x-coord, y-coord )
```

x-coord is the pixel along the horizontal axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.

y-coord is the pixel along the vertical axis of the document that you want displayed in the upper left.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with the plugin in the 'external resources': http://jsfiddle.net/LKu6p/1/

Your code is right, the plugin isn't loading for some reason. Check the `<head>` area of the code to check that it's there and if it is, whether the path to the file is correct.

However, I agree with Royi - if you can do this without a plugin, all the better.